# waitpid returns 0 when SIGINT (Crtl+c) on a children

Tags: c, waitpid

I'm working in a terminal for an university work, but I'm having troubles when looking for finished children.

I have a list in which i save the background processes and this works fine, but when i bring it to the foreground and i send him a `SIGINT` signal with ctrl+c the `waitpid` returns 1 on all unfinished children but the one I kill. That's my code. I'm sure that my error is in that `waitpid`, but I don't know why returns a wrong value. What I want my code to do is to select when I kill a process with `SIGINT` and kill this one and remove this from the list but keep the unfinished commands.

```
int emptyBackground(List *list){ 

    ListNode *aux = list->first;
    ListNode *aux2 = NULL; 

    while(aux != NULL){
        if(waitpid(aux->pid, NULL, WNOHANG) > 0){ // This waitpid returns a non expected value
            if(aux2 != NULL){
                aux2->next = aux->next;
                free(aux);
                aux = aux2->next;
            }else{
                list->first = aux->next;
                free(aux);
                aux = list->first;
            }
        }else{
            aux2 = aux;
            aux = aux->next;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

PD: My list has the command pid, the command and a pointer to the next node.

Comment: The code you show doesn’t record the value returned by `waitpid()`, and you ignore the exit status information.  If I were debugging it, I’d be capturing and printing or logging both bits of information.

Answer (score 3):

`waitpid` should never return `1`. It should return either `-1`, `0`, or the `pid` of the child that exited. Try using the `wstatus` field of `waitpid` to debug exactly what `waitpid` thinks happened to the child.

Comment: ... and pid 1 is the primordial process, traditionally `init`; it is never the child of another process.